# formatting to json in vtl appsync

Tags: json, string, amazon-web-services, vtl

How can I convert to JSON object the following string in my appsync resolver?:

`"\n\n    {executionArn=arn:aws:states:us-west-2:937872248779:execution:dm-rules-analysis-execution-wfl-dev-state-machine:494ab72d-49a7-4e82-aa39-dab2dc755206, startDate=1.686867433029E9}\n\n"`

`$util.parseJson()` does not work.